# Remove pound symbol from url django

Tags: django, url, navigation, bootstrap-4, django-urls

So, I have a standard bootstrap one page site. I am using django as the backend. for each section of the site, I use the html id I give to it to navigate to it from the navbar.

the only problem is that I cannot figure out how to clean the pound sign from the url. I still want something like:

`example.com/contact`

navigate to the contact section automatically, however, right it looks like:

`example.com/#contact`

How do I go about changing this? Is it something I need to add to the django urls.py file?

Comment: You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I don't understand how Django is involved in this questions; do you want to do a front-end URL hashchange? Or do you want to pass `#contact` to the backend?

Comment: Browsers manage #contact of url and use it as page bookmarks [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp]. you cannot send it to backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go about changing this? Is it something I need to add to the
>   django urls.py file?

No.

`#` in URL is a [Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

From https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

> ... fragment identifier is only used by the
>   browser – it doesn’t affect which resource is returned from the server.

As it's used by the browser you cannot do much about it unless you change your navigation implementation.